# Getting ERROR while uploading certificate of .pfx format

Tags: python, openssl, certificate

I have a certificate called "MyCert.pfx" with some passphrase say "buggy" and 2 different working server S1 and S2. With S1 uploading and usage of this cert is absolutely fine but While uploading this certificate to S2, I am getting below error:
**['asn1 encoding routines', 'ASN1_CHECK_TLEN', 'wrong tag']['asn1 encoding routines', 'asn1_item_embed_d2i', 'nested asn1 error]**

**Traceback:**
n File \"/opt/aruba/central/apps/configuration/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py\", line 3046, in load_pkcs12
n _raise_current_error()
n File \"/opt/aruba/central/apps/configuration/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py\", line 54, in exception_from_error_queue
n raise exception_type(errors)
nError: [(\'asn1 encoding routines\', \'asn1_check_tlen\', \'wrong tag\'), (\'asn1 encoding routines\', \'asn1_item_embed_d2i\', \'nested asn1 error\')]'

Any idea why the same certificate is working in one place but not on the other ? When I converted it to .PEM it is working fine at both the places.

Comment: How did you created the cert? It looks like its self-signed cert. If you created the certs on working server using OpenSSL, run OpenSSL on secod server too. There might be a step that OpenSSL makes while creating cert. I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks @slon. let me try your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case it was due to new OpenSSL version vs. old node.js installed on the server.

I found the solution [here](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/issues/126#issuecomment-233498554):

> Run the following command to fix the key:
>
> ```
> openssl rsa -in key.txt -out key.txt
> ```

*Where **key.txt** is the private key file.*